# Json Deserialization failed on token and has left off in the middle of parsing a row

Tags: bulk-api, python, simple-salesforce, bulk-api-v2

I am trying to bulk load a csv file with 11000 records using Python with the simple-salesforce API.

The error that I am running into is that when I try to load the file, I get this message:

```
{'created': False,
  'errors': [{'fields': ['external_field__c'],
              'message': "Json Deserialization failed on token 'external_field__c' "
                         'and has left off in the middle of parsing a row. '
                         'Will go to end of row to begin parsing the next row',
              'statusCode': 'INVALID_FIELD'}]
```

I am able to load just one record using my code, but anything greater than 1 then I get the JSON Deserialization error. I have validated that the API name in the Object Manager is the same as what I am trying to upload.

This is my code:

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
from pprint import pprint
import json
import pandas as pd
from pandas import json_normalize
from sfbulk2 import SFBulk2
import requests
import csv
from salesforce_bulk import CsvDictsAdapter


load_data = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\BlahBlah\\Desktop\\test_csv4.csv')   
load_data = load_data.fillna('')
print(load_data)
bulk_data = []
for row in load_data.itertuples():
    d = row._asdict()
    del d['Index']
    bulk_data.append(d)

sf = Salesforce(username='username', password='password', security_token='token', domain='test')    
x = sf.bulk.Account.upsert(bulk_data,batch_size=10000, external_id_field='external_field__c')
pprint(x)
```

I am thinking that there might be something very simple I could be missing with this code, but I have tried to research this issue for hours without getting anywhere.

Edit Adding "fake" data:

````
external_ID__c,LastName,FirstName,MiddleName,PersonBirthdate,RecordTypeId,Phone,PersonMailingStreet,PersonMailingCity,PersonMailingState,PersonMailingPostalCode,PeronMailingCountry
9999,SMITH,JOHN,,1970-01-01,XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,99999999999,123 ANY STREET,ANYTOWN,NY,10001,USA```
````

Comment: [SFDMU](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SFDX-Data-Move-Utility) does this out of the box

Comment: could you add the file you are trying to upload?
I mean the one which works and the other which doesn't work?

Comment: @identigral Unfortunately this will not work for me since I need to be able to extract data from a DB to transfer in to Salesforce on a scheduled basis. I wish that this could work for me.

Comment: @EliveltonWalter Basically the data where one record uploads has the header and one record to it. The other one has about 10 records in it with the header row. Both files are comma delimited. I cannot add the file due to confidentiality reasons, but it's basically a simple demographics file with things like Name, Address, Internal Id Number, etc.

Comment: @Perdue Your question is about loading from CSV. SFDMU does this.

Comment: @Perdue ok, then can you insert some fake data into the database and print them and add to the question?
I feel like if it works with one record and not with more, it could be how the data is on the DB, it is will really help if you can show that for us

Comment: @identigral Does SFDMU load CSV files on a scheduled basis? I have tried to see if it does this, and I cannot find any documentation on how to schedule SFDMU to load a CSV file.

Comment: @EliveltonWalter I was able to make some progress with the date of birth field since it was a timestamp in the DB while Salesforce had it in a date format. As far as faking the data, I don't know how much more I could add other than it would be like the header as I have above and one row such as John Smith, 123 Any Street, 99999, 1970-01-01. That's pretty much what it looks like in my data set.

Comment: @Perdue It's a command-line app, you can schedule it via cron/sched task/launchd/...

Comment: @identigral Do you have any website that can show me how this is done?

Comment: If you're on a Windows device: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195503/setting-up-a-cron-job-in-windows

Comment: @identigral I guess I am going to have to experiment with this more because I am not seeing right away how to get SFDMU to work with what I need. Basically I have a view in our DB that updates a population on a nightly basis in Salesforce. This view does not update all of the columns in the sObject, so I am not sure just by looking at the SFDMU documentation if this solution would work for my company's current needs. It seems more complicated to set up than what I am currently trying to do via Python.

Comment: That would be a [few lines of JSON config in SFDMU](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SFDX-Data-Move-Utility/issues/518). Having said that, fair enough - if you're more comfortable with Python, then do that.

Comment: @identigral This would have to be one of those things that I would need more time to research and figure out. It could be potentially faster to set up, but I would need to figure out how to do this from scratch. From the example you provided, it does not seem to say how to tell in the JSON file where the csv file is located. Is it that done outside of the JSON file? Also, is the SOQL the method to say which columns need to be upserted?

Comment: @Perdue It's a command-line app, you specify [runtime options](https://help.sfdmu.com/plugin-basics/basic-usage/running) such as the CSV's location via arguments passed to the program. Yes, via SOQL. Try [Quick Start](https://help.sfdmu.com/quick-start)